How does Python 3 use ‘pexpect’ to automatically interact with serial ports?
How to use Python ‘pexpect’ in Windows to automatically interact with a serial port (eg., COM3) and enter the user password when logging in to an embedded development board via serial port at power-on?
ser = serial.Serial(port=serial_port, baudrate=baudrate, bytesize=bytesize, parity=parity, stopbits=stopbits, timeout=timeout) 
channel = pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn(ser.fileno(), timeout=180)

** Exception: fileno **
There seems to be something wrong with fileno.
(python 3.11)
I tried, unsuccessfully, to manipulate this serial with Pexpect, and wondered if there was another way to automatically interact with the serial port, such as automatically entering a login password from the serial port.

I tried to use ‘ser.readline()’ to handle serial data, but it was cumbersome and the interaction was not ideal
